# Facebook like button and weird image on the wall

Tags: facebook-like

I've included a like box plugin in my page:

```
<div class="fb-like" id="fb" data-href="http://www.lorem.com" data-send="false"
     data-layout="button_count" data-width="60" data-show-faces="true"></div>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

after click 'Like' and posted to the facebook's wall, I see that the image is weird, I mean i see it is only a small piece of my site's logo. That image on the wall looks like this

[image]

what shall I do to make that image to be looking good ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was, the minimum size of the image should be 200x200, mine was 330x40. And also, the image url should be placed in the `og:image` meta tag